# How can I assign output to two bash arrays variables

Tags: linux, bash, sh

There are vaguely similar answers here but nothing that could really answer my question.  I am at a point in my bash script where I have to fill two arrays from an output that looks like the following:

```
part-of-the-file1:line_32
part-of-the-file1:line_97
part-of-the-file2:line_88
part-of-the-file2:line_93
```

What I need to do is pull out the files and line numbers in there own separate arrays.  So far I have:

`read FILES LINES <<<($(echo $INPUTFILES | xargs grep -n $id | cut -f1,2 -d':' | awk '{print $1 " " $2}'`
with a modified `IFS=':'` but this doesn't work.  I'm sure there are better solutions since I am NOT a scripting or tools wizard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`read` cannot populate two *arrays* at a time like it can populate two regular parameters using word-splitting. It's best to just iterate over the output of your pipeline to build the arrays.

```
while IFS=: read fname lineno therest; do
  files+=("$fname")
  lines+=("$lineno")
done < <(echo $INPUTFILES | xargs grep -n "$id")
```

Here, I'm letting `read` do the splitting and discarding of the the tail end of `grep`'s output in place of using `cut` and `awk`.

Comment: @jnbbender, if this is then answer, [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)